# Vite build with dynamic imports of Vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, es6-modules

I have a project built with Vite that dynamically imports Vue components (via `async import(filename + '.js')`) that are not known at build time.

Those vue components depend on vue, and are built with rollup configured to output `import { xyz } from 'vue'`; with Vue set as an external.

Right now, however, the imported Vue components throw that they can't find the module vue (because it's not available in the import map or known to the browser) and fail to run.

How do I set up the main Vite project so it can async import Vue components that are not known at build time and they have access to the modules that are already loaded at runtime?

This is all to support a project which allows plugins in the form of view components, so it's not possible at build time to know which plugins (and this components) will be available.

Vite config of parent project:

```js
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    root: 'ui',
    build: {
        outDir: '../dist'
    },
})
```

Vite config of component:

```js
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    build: {
        outDir: './resources',
        lib: {
            // Could also be a dictionary or array of multiple entry points
            entry: resolve(__dirname, 'ui/index.js'),
            name: 'UIExample',
            // the proper extensions will be added
            fileName: 'ui-example',
          },
          rollupOptions: {
            // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
            // into your library
            external: ['vue'],
            output: {
              // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
              // for externalized deps
              globals: {
                vue: 'Vue',
              },
            },
          }
    },
})
```

Failing import:

```js
const component = await import(`plugins/${plugin.src.name}.mjs`)
```

(where plugins/filename.mjs is being served by the same web server that the main project is running on)

Comment: It's unknown what these plugins look like. You probably need module federation or something else

Comment: This might help you - [Distributed Vue.js Applications Part 1: Loading Components via HTTP](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/)

Comment: Try [runtime template compiler](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/4158)?

Comment: I have partial control of the plugins (i.e. I can define how they should look) and am currently building them with rollup. So shouldn't need to compile them at runtime, I just need them to have access to the same copy of Vue that's on the page.